# Jenkins Remote Parameterized : ExceedRetryLimitException

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to trigger a Remote Job from my Local Jenkins server. I did all required configuration for Parameterized Remote Trigger like Remote Host setup, Job info for Local server job. But when I triggered the job, I am getting following error :

```
Triggering remote job now.
CSRF protection is disabled on the remote server.
ERROR: Remote build failed with 'ExceedRetryLimitException' for the following reason: 'Max number of connection retries have been exeeded.'. But the build will continue.
ERROR: Unexpected status: status=NOT_TRIGGERED. The queue id was not found.
Skipped archiving because build is not successful
Extended Email Publisher is currently disabled in project settings
Finished: FAILURE
```

I checked the credentials which is perfectly fine and tried enabling and disabling CSRF (Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits).

Am I missing anything? Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

As Jenkins upgrade did some change on CSRF validation.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.176/#SECURITY-626

Install a plugin named Strict Crumb Issuer Plugin and set like this works for me

[image]